# Adding an int Array after modification but ends up adding the old int Array

Tags: java, arrays, collections, integer, permutation

I'm writing code to take an int[] and adding all of its permutations to a Collection. The code works and makes the correct swaps. Before adding it to the Stack, I have a print statement showing me my array before adding it:

```
132
213
231
312
321
```

But then when I print the arrays in the stack after the permutations are done, I get:

```
321
321
321
321
321
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with how Java handles the array and how the int[] is being added but I'm not sure.

Code here:

```
    public Stack<int[]> perm(int[] labels) {
        Stack<int[]> perm = new Stack<int[]>();

        int[] value = labels;
        Arrays.sort(value);
        int k = labels.length;

        boolean permutationsComplete = false;
        perm.add(value);

        while (!permutationsComplete) {
            
            int i = k - 1;
            while (i > 0 && value[i - 1] >= value[i]) {
                i--;
            }

            if (i < 1) {
                permutationsComplete = true;
                System.out.println();
                for(int[] list : perm) {
                    this.printList(list);
                }
                return perm;
            }

            int j = k;
            while (value[j - 1] <= value[i - 1]) {
                j--;
            }

            int swap1 = value[i - 1];
            value[i - 1] = value[j - 1];
            value[j - 1] = swap1;

            i++;
            j = k;

            while (i < j) {
                int swap2 = value[i - 1];
                value[i - 1] = value[j - 1];
                value[j - 1] = swap2;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
            perm.add(value);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: replace your printing with Arrays.toString(perm.toArray())

Comment: Its not a printing issue. I've verified that the stack contains the printed values with a debugger.

Comment: Please include the code that calls the `perm` method and prints the stack contents after the `perm` method exits.

Comment: By the way, how do you know the code works?

Comment: Shown in the first output, the permutations of 123 are correctly made before adding to the stack. Ive tried it for other numbers as well. I know the permutations are being found correctly. Its after its added to a collection that all lists in the collection change to the last added list.

Comment: You're dealing with a single array and add this single array multiple times to the Stack. It doesn't matter whether you modify the array, it is the same array all the time.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking as well and I guess I'm drawing a blank as to how I get around that. I've tried creating a new list before its added to the stack but I guess I'll have to create a new list and manually iterate through "values" and add the values to it

Comment: I think @Mihe  is right.  In Java, arrays are reference types.  So `int[] value = labels;`  makes `value` and `labels` the same array. What happens to one happens to the other.  If you want them to be different arrays use `Arrays.copyOf`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Arrays.CopyOf seems way easier than my plan so thank you! Ill give that a shot

Comment: If you don’t need to change the length, you can also use `int[] value = labels.clone();`

Answer (score 1):

Answers were in the comments but basically the way I was trying to copy the arrays to new arrays was assigning different references to the same array object. By replacing:

```
perm.add(value);
```

with:

```
int[] newValue = Arrays.CopyOf(value, value.length);
perm.add(newValue);
```

I was able to get around this. I'm sure there's a cleaner way to write this code but for now this gets me what I need.

Comment: If you think fewer lines is "cleaner", which is not always the case, and is often a matter of opinion, you could replace the two lines with 1:  `perm.add(Arrays.copyOf(Value, value.length);`

Comment: Or even shorter, `perm.add(value.clone());`

Comment: Nice I like that as well